# Dynamically allocating classes, with Inheritance issue

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-allocation

I am trying to dynamically allocate an array of base(Student) classes, and then assign pointers to derived(Math) classes to each array slot. I can get it to work by creating a single pointer to the base class, and then assigning that to a derived class, but when I attempt to assign to the pointer to a dynamically allocated array of base classes, it fails. I have posted the fragments of code that I am using below. So basically my question is, why isn't the dynamically allocated one working?

```
   Student* studentList = new Student[numStudents];  
   Math* temp = new Math(name, l, c, q, t1, t2, f);  
   studentList[0] = temp;                                 

/*Fragment Above Gives Error:

main.cpp: In function âint main()â:
main.cpp:55: error: no match for âoperator=â in â* studentList = tempâ
grades.h:13: note: candidates are: Student& Student::operator=(const Student&)*/



   Student * testptr;
   Math * temp = new Math(name, l, c, q, t1, t2, f);
   testptr = temp
   //Works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`studentList[0]` is not a pointer (i.e. a `Student *`), it's an object (i.e. a `Student`).

It sounds a bit like what you need is an array of pointers.  In which case, you should do something like:

```
Student **studentList = new Student *[numStudents];
Math *temp = new Math(name, l, c, q, t1, t2, f);
studentList[0] = temp;
```

In this snippet, the type of `studentList` is `Student **`.  Therefore, the type of `studentList[0]` is `Student *`.

(Note that in C++, there are better, safer ways to do this, involving container classes and smart pointers.  However, that's beyond the scope of the question.)

Comment: Alright, I did see this in the C++ book I am learning from somewhere, so i'll have to review that.

Comment: `new Student *[numStudents];` Why is there a pointer there? Is the only part of this that I do not understand.

Comment: @dubyaa: Because you need to create an array of items, each of which is a `Student *`.